# SQL Teradata- Syntax error while removing duplicates using row_number() over

Tags: sql, duplicates, teradata, row-number

I need to delete duplicates from a table. I've tried to do this following exactly the code from [this website](https://www.sqlshack.com/different-ways-to-sql-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-sql-table/) as well as [this](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/delete-duplicates-sql-server/)

```
    WITH cte (Id, 
    Proname, 
    Cityname, 
    Companyname,
    ItemsNo,
    row_num) 
    AS (SELECT 
    Id, 
    Proname, 
    Cityname, 
    Companyname,
    ItemsNo,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY 
    Id, 
    Proname, 
    Cityname, 
    Companyname
    ORDER BY 
    Id, 
    Proname, 
    Cityname, 
    Companyname) AS row_num
    FROM dba.tabdupes)
    DELETE FROM cte
    WHERE row_num > 1;
```

but every time I'm getting a syntax error in Teradata:
[3707]syntax error expected something like a 'SELECT' keyword or '(' or a 'TRANSACTION TIME' keyword or a 'VALIDRIME' keyword between ')' and the 'DELETE' keyword.

I've tried multiple solutions but can't get what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to `DELETE` "all but one" row from a set of duplicate rows in a table. You can eliminate duplicates within the result set of a `SELECT`, and `INSERT` the result into a second table.
Teradata's special "SET" tables will also quietly remove entirely duplicate rows when you do an `INSERT ... SELECT` though whether that performs well depends on how unique the primary index values are in the target table.

Comment: Also, Teradata allows CTEs only as part of a `SELECT` (including the `SELECT` part of `INSERT ... SELECT`.)

Answer (score 0):

Teradata is not SQL server.

You could try following approach

## But before you run the cede

make a Backup of your database, or make da test database to run  tessif the query does make that what you want

```
DELETE dba.tabdupes
 FROM (
    SELECT 
    Id, Proname, Cityname,  Companyname, ItemsNo
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Id, Proname, Cityname, Companyname ORDER BY Id, Proname, Cityname, Companyname) AS row_num
    FROM dba.tabdupes) AS d, edba.tabdupes t
    WHERE t.id = d.id
 AND   row_num = 1
```